# Help identifying an SMD chip

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, surface-mount

[image]

I have stumbled upon this mystery chip, it is probably a voltage regulator. It is inside a projector I want to repair. From what I gather, it's probably a 1.8 volt regulator.

If you can confirm please go ahead. The package is SOT-223.

Comment: Week 17 2018? Dead already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dii` is the logo for [Diodes Incorporated](https://www.diodes.com).

At first, "4aG" looks like a possible [SMD marking code](https://www.electronica-pt.com/db/smd.php?ref=4AG) as this shows several 1.8V regulators, but *none by DI.* Checking DI datasheets, it looks more like "17-18" is the device marking, "18" being 1.8V and "17" being the model.  The only DI datasheet I could find which shows this naming format is [this one](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP7363.pdf) page 10:

[image: AP7363 Datasheet]

So it is definitely a DI linear regulator, 1.8V, model "17", in a SOT-223 package.  But none of the models ending in *17 have a datasheet which matches this marking.

Could be that the device was custom-made or is outdated, relabeled, etc.

Chances are good the 63-18 could be an equivalent, but you'll want to make sure the pins are in the same order first of course.

Comment: that matches what I have found so far so thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about the first two or three symbols. Looks like an incomplete "DH" or something. But the 17-18 on the second row is at least a little familiar. Onsemi uses that for an obsolete 1.8V regulator with part number [NCP1117ST18T3](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1117-d.pdf).